# SpicIE toolbar, SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2 execScript problem?

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm developing an addon for IE8+.

Main function:
- when I click the toolbar, it will display a box inside every single page, ex: google.com, bing.com, codeproject.com... by using execScript to execute jQuery.
Therefore, what Im doing is run javascript in the current page.

Everything has done except when that page perform an Pop-up, it doesnt work anymore.
I click the toolbar, nothing happen, but when I look at the pop-up, surprise! has the box which im trying to display. So, I think the current tab and the popup of its is running the same process.

I have change registry key TabProcGrowth to 20, to make sure every single tab run by its own process, but maybe it not work with popup.

sr for my bad english, any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

***update:***
I have changed the way to develop my addon, so I change my question, too. (But any suggestion for the 1st question still very useful for me).

My new question still mention the "execScript" problem.

HOW to execute javascript with every individual tab of IE browser with TabProcGrowth = 0. I need this value set to 0 because I have the timer to request to the server every interval1 (ex: 60s). So if there are more than one processes of IE, the addon will send multi request to server at the sametime.

In my situation now, I set TabProcGrowth to 0. Open IE, open some tabs. Click the toolbar at the newest tab, it works, ofcourse!. But when I click toolbar at the old one, nothing happen. The script still be execute but it takes effect on the newest tab.

It's the big problem for me, resolve this problem, you guys save my life.